# How to use android expansion files in ionic 2 and visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ionic2, apk-expansion-files

I am currently developing an app using visual studio and ionic 2. 
The problem is when I compile the Apk. Its size is too large (over 200 MB) and Google only allows for Apk's of 100 MB.

I have tried reducing the size of the images but it is still over 100 MB in size.

My question is how do i use the expansion files in visual studio?

I have not seen any examples on it.

I have searched but it only brings up answers for java?

Comment: did you build ionic app with command ionic build android --prod ?

Comment: @SuryaTeja yes i did